# GROUP BY and add calculate percentage

Tags: sql

I have following table:

| %alcohol | rating | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 4 | 5 |
| 6 | 5 | 3 |
| 7 | 6 | 3 |
| 4 | 7 | 2 |
| 4 | 8 | 1 |
| 4 | 9 | 5 |

with SQL commands I want to calculate the partition of the %alcohol:

| %alcohol | rating | count | percentage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 7 | 2 | 25 |
| 4 | 8 | 1 | 12.5 |
| 4 | 9 | 5 | 62.5 |
| 6 | 5 | 3 | 100 |
| 7 | 4 | 5 | 62.5 |
| 7 | 6 | 3 | 37.5 |

I already tried it with following command, but it didnt work

```
WITH number_of_rating AS
(
  SELECT AlcoholPercentage, Rating, Count(*) AS number_of_rating_per_percentage
  FROM Beer
  GROUP BY Beer, Rating)
SELECT AlcoholPercentage, Rating, number_of_rating_per_percentage, 
  (0.0+number_of_rating_per_percentage)/(COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY AlcoholPercentage)) AS Portion
FROM number_of_rating;
```

Answer (score 0):

Most databases support *Window functions*:

```
select *, 
  "Count" * 1.0 / Sum("count") over(partition by "%alcohol") * 100 as Percentage
from Beer
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE(ALCOHOL,RATING,COUNT)AS
(
  SELECT  7 ,   4 , 5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 6 ,    5 , 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 7 ,    6,  3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 ,    7,  2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 ,    8,  1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 ,    9,  5
)
 SELECT C.ALCOHOL,C.RATING,C.COUNT,
 CAST((CAST(C.COUNT AS DECIMAL(20,2))/CAST(SUM(C.COUNT)OVER(PARTITION BY C.ALCOHOL)AS DECIMAL(20,2)))*100.00 AS DECIMAL(20,2)) AS PER_CENTAGE
FROM CTE AS C
```

Enjoy your beer